# Fire custom events without using GTM dataLayer in order to activate Google Optimize

Tags: javascript, angular, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-optimize

**CONTEXT**

I am implementing Google Optimize on an Angular 2 application. I have found numerous resources stating optimize must be triggered on custom events (for example http://blog.stack.foundation/2017/06/02/using-google-optimize-with-angular/).

This is because Angular2 needs to first render on the client side before Optimize can apply variations, so page load is not a suitable trigger. This is done through the following snippet:

```
window['dataLayer'].push({'event': 'optimize.activate'});
```

and specifying `Evaluate on custom event: optimize.activate` in Google Optimize.

**Problem**

Datalayer is a Google Tag Manager feature, and currently my website does not, and preferably will not implement Google Tag Manager. Is there an alternative way to fire custom events that does not require GTM? Can I format GA events to activate Optimize instead of GTM dataLayer Events?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Even though dataLayer is a Tag Manager feature, Optimize uses the variable to send info and you **do NOT need to add GTM to use Google Optimize**.

You will just have to create a dataLayer variable that just conforms to [Data Layer - GTM specifications](https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/devguide#datalayer) instead of a simple javascript variable. 
Rest will work.

Also ensure that you do not override dataLayer variable and declare it above the optimize code.

Answer (score 0):

Can you push multiple events into the `dataLayer` at the same time?  ask because of it would be useful for me as these values can be used for different triggers. I am using this for tracking two different events and user id.

```
<script>
    var dataLayer = window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
    dataLayer.push({'event': 'Click Map Event'});
    dataLayer.push({'event': '5Sec Event'}); 
    dataLayer.push({'event':'UserID Event','userID': '12483'});
</script>
```